# Best choice for storing and lookup in 40 million short strings?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, web-scraping

I'm writing a sort of multithreaded web-scraper and need to store really large amount of currently processed IDs (they are strings, 20-25 digits length), and my crawling algorithm requires approximately equal number of insertions and lookups (lookup is a check, whether given ID is present in a database). So I'm looking for some software, that will help me in doing this, can you, please, advise me something?

Currently I'm thinking of MySQL with indexing (because MySQL is easy to use and it is thread-safe [I need thread-safety]), but maybe there are another great choices?

Thank you.